# How to touch COM in Windows from Python 2.7

Tags: python, com

In Python 2.4, I can do...

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
```

Apparently win32com does not exist in Python 2.7. Was it just renamed? Do I need to install another module?

Comment: `pywin32` is available on Python 2.3-3.1  http://sf.net/projects/pywin32 There is no need for a strong language.

Comment: The `pywin32` module isn't part of the core language (for obvious reasons). Generally you'll to upgrade it whenever you upgrade the version of Python you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Apparently win32com does not exist in
>   Python 2.7

it didn't exist in Python 2.4 either.
you need to install pywin32.  you must have done this at some point in your 2.4 setup.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

after you install that, you should be able to do:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup, you may need some extra modules. [This](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html) page seems to have the best explained data on the matter

Answer (score 0):

comtypes is more advance library that allow low level COM work.